# Adding registry keys via .reg file

Tags: com, registry, key

I have a small problem that I'm sure has a simple solution, although its only simple when you know how.

Using Windows8, I want to register my COM dll. I'm doing this via a .reg file. The problem comes with adding the InprocServer32 entry. For some reason the value that will point to my .dll file doesn't actually get added into the registry. The InprocServer32 key gets added but not the value.

I have this entry within the .reg file...

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{15C9923A-7847-4249-95C5-E521D8D614C9}\InprocServer32]
@="D:\COMTest\TestIObject.dll"
"ThreadingModel" = "Both"
```

There are several other entries that get added correctly, just not the 'value' of the InprocServer32. The ThreadingModel key and value are added as expected. Is the 'InprocServer32' key value protected against being added/changed in Windows8? If so what would be the correct solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the backslash characters in the path:

```
@="D:\\COMTest\\TestIObject.dll"
```

Comment: Thankyou for your reply. Worked a treat!

I edited my reply as I forgot to save the file before trying again!
Sorry.

Comment: Have you tried to completely remove `[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\...\InprocServer32]` key first?